# Check StumbleUpon followers

Tags: php, api

I want to develop an application for stumbleupon and I need to check if somebody follow another person on StumbleUpon. For example, user X follow user Y, user X need to press an button to confirm and I want to check with php, if user X followed user Y. If user X follow User Y, continue. Somebody know how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a function that goes like this:

```
function followed($follower,$followed){
    $response = @file_get_contents('http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/'.$follower.'/following/');
    return (strpos($response,'/stumbler/'.$followed.'/') !== false);
}
```

it will return if the user already followed your target stumbler

Hope this helps.

Comment: After some tests here is a little problem, for example if I follow more than 30 users and I follow now somebody who will be on page 2 (with followers), this function don't work, work just if people followed is on first page with followers, not on another page.